# How can I determine the data source value to a connectionstring in sql server 2012 when using (LocalDb)\v11.0 in a workgroup and not a domain?

Tags: iis, hosting, connection-string, datasource, sql-server-2012

Environment: 64 bit Windows 8

Platform: Visual Studio 2012, SQL server 2012, IIS8

Language: C#

I'm currently creating an asp.net web application using a tutorial from msdn. The site runs fine and is visible in google chrome when I select the run button. I published the website to a folder on my desktop and am attempting to host it through IIS. The main issue I am having is trying to figure out the full computer name so I can update my connection strings in the web.cong.

The connection string is as follows:

connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb\v11.0);"

When I try to browse the website in IIS I get a database error because I'm not defining the full machine name in the datasource attribute. I'm in a workgroup and am not on a domain. Also I can't log into sql server with just my ip address. I can only log into sql server with (LocalDb)\v11.0.

Can anyone help me find a way to determine what the value of my data source should be so I can possibly hit the website externally? Has anyone run into this problem on a home pc without a domain? I have done this on my work computer many times but have never tried to host anything from IIS on my home computer.

Comment: After further research it seems that I should be able to run my application using (LocalDb\v11.0). I'm running into the same problem this **[article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx#comments)** is trying to solve and can't get "The server was not found or was not accessible." error to go away. It would be interesting to see if anyone else has been able to host anything in iis8 using (LocalDb\v11.0)